# Create llvm metadata node with constantInt

Tags: metadata, llvm, constants

While the language reference mention a lot about the LLVM Metadata,

and I see some posts on SO - [How to add a Metadata String to an LLVM module with the C++ API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973570/how-to-add-a-metadata-string-to-an-llvm-module-with-the-c-api)

I also see some code in the llvm source- 
http://llvm.org/doxygen/DIBuilder_8cpp_source.html

However, they dont seem to mention how to create a MDNode containing a **ConstantInt** of a particular width.

**Following is the relevant code** (***doesn't work*** ) -

```
std::vector<Metadata*> Elts = 
{
      ConstantInt::get(TheContext,APInt(returnType->getIntegerBitWidth(),decimal_val)) 
};



MDNode* Node = MDNode::get(TheContext, Elts);
callInst->setMetadata(LLVMContext::MD_range,Node);
```

Can anyone explain how this can be done ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written [this](http://jiten-thakkar.com/posts/how-to-read-and-write-metadata-in-llvm) small post about how to insert metadata in LLVM IR. You can refer that. Basically you need to use [ConstantAsMetadata](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ConstantAsMetadata.html#a703ab6c3e14ff7565866468d731f537a) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I checked the llvm class hierarchy and checked the sub-classes
under MetaData. I found a few classes and one of them was - ConstantAsMetadata

The **change** in the above code that works for me is -

```
std::vector<Metadata*> Elts = {
    ConstantAsMetadata::get(ConstantInt::get(TheContext,APInt(returnType,0)) ),

ConstantAsMetadata::get(ConstantInt::get(TheContext,APInt(returnType,decimal_val)) )    

  };
```

**Note**- You should ( if you want correctness ) specify a pair of numbers for each range that you are trying to create.

If you are using the verifier pass provided by llvm , the above would not work/make sense if you just have a single ConstantInt inside the initializer.
This is because of an assert inside the Verifier pass provided by the llvm.